# How to use outputText in xhtml file to display the value given by the function? Why is this giving me error?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

This  is my code in Java and I am trying to get the outputText in my xhtml to print the value of the double, but it's giving me the the following error: /dummy2.xhtml @19,41 value="#{bill.GenBill}": Property 'GenBill' not found on type Bill

```
 import java.io.Serializable;
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.sql.Statement;

    import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
    import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
    import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
    import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
    import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

    @ManagedBean(name="bill")
    @ViewScoped

    public class Bill {



        public double GenBill(){


            return 4.565654;

        }

    }
```

dummy2.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

<h:head>

</h:head>

<h:body>
<h:form>

<h:outputText value="#{bill.GenBill}" />

</h:form>

</h:body>

</html>
```

I would like to have the output of the GenBill() method as a double in the dummy2.xhtml file on the web browser to proceed in my project.

Thanks,
ANM

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you, and your error - you need to follow Java bean standard naming conventions because it's going to use bean introspection and serialization. So, I'm pretty sure you need

```
public class Bill implements Serializable { // <-- note implements
  private double genBill = 4.565654;
  public double getGenBill() {
    return genBill; 
  }
  // I'm not sure if setGenBill() is strictly necessary here.
  public void setGenBill(double genBill) {
    this.genBill = genBill;
  }
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L; // <-- provide a version 
                                                   //     for Serialization
}
```

The relevant error

> Property 'GenBill' not found on type Bill

Answer (score 0):

like this , add"()":

```
<h:outputText value="#{bill.GenBill()}" />
```

or add  get method for bean:

```
public class Bill {

    public double getBill(){
        return  4.565654;
    }

    public double GenBill(){


        return 4.565654;

    }

}
```

then you can do this :

```
<h:outputText value="#{bill.bill}" />
```

Comment: @Ace - If the answer resolves the issue, please accept it. yzc, an explanation of why/how your answer works will greatly improve the quality of your answer